# How to position text widget in stack for different screen sizes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to place some text over the image and due to variable screen size the text widget balance for one screen sizes not balacing in someother screen sizes.

The output I need is like the image

[image]

I'm using name in place of "Some text here". So, I tried balance the text widget with my code and now I tested on another device with different screen size and the "Some text here" came to the inner red border bottom.

How to solve this thing? I've tried some code and let me place it for you.

```
Widget imageStack() {
    print("Width: " + (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width).toString());
    return
        // Padding(
        //   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4),
        //   child:
        AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1,
      child: SizedBox(
        // height: 700,
        width: 170,
        child: Stack(
          // fit: StackFit.loose,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 120,
              left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4 + 20,
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Image(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 200,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: NetworkImage(data['image']),
                  )),
            ),
            const Positioned.fill(
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Image(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/images/fomat.png')))),
            Positioned(
              // top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.68,
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 395
                  ? 295
                  : 295 + MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 48,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(data['name'],
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      // fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    )),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 25,
              right: 25,
              child: Align(
                // alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Text(
                  dob.toString(),
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      // ),
    );
  }

  dynamic directory;
  imageShareReady() async {
    directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  }

  final screenshotController = ScreenshotController();
  late Uint8List _imageFile;

  _saveImage(Uint8List bytes) async {
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(_imageFile);
    print("Result: " + result.toString());
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SharedManager().showSnackBar("Image Saved to gallery!"));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column(
        // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
          ),
          Screenshot(controller: screenshotController, child: imageStack()),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
        backgroundColor: ColorsManager.appColor,
        animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
        children: [
          SpeedDialChild(
            onTap: () {
              // Navigator.of(context).pop();
              // screenshotController
              //     .captureFromWidget(imageStack())
              //     .then((image) {
              //   setState(() {
              //     _imageFile = image;
              //     _saveImage(_imageFile);
              //   });
              // });
              screenshotController.capture().then((image) {
                setState(() {
                  _imageFile = image!;
                  _saveImage(_imageFile);
                });
              }).catchError((onError) {
                print("Error: " + onError.toString());
              });
            },
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.save,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            backgroundColor: ColorsManager.appColor,
          ),
          SpeedDialChild(
            onTap: () async {
              // screenshotController
              //     .captureFromWidget(imageStack())
              //     .then((image) {
              //   setState(() {
              //     final imageFileSave = File(
              //         '${directory.path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png');
              //     imageFileSave.writeAsBytesSync(image);
              //     Share.shareFiles([imageFileSave.path]);
              //   });
              // });
              screenshotController.capture().then((image) {
                setState(() {
                  final imageFileSave = File(
                      '${directory.path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png');
                  imageFileSave.writeAsBytesSync(image!);
                  Share.shareFiles([imageFileSave.path]);
                });
              });
            },
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.share,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            backgroundColor: ColorsManager.appColor,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      // ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It is possible to have overlap due to screen size and font-size, in this case I will prefer Stack with inner column or just Container with column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `LayoutBuilder` to get the size. I will encourage you to check [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget.

```dart
 
class ImageStack extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageStack({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            ///Background image
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 12, color: Colors.red)),
            ),
            Align(
              /// positioded the column
              alignment: Alignment(0, .1),

              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  /// inner container
                  Container(
                    height: constraints.maxHeight / 3,
                    width: constraints.maxWidth / 3,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 12, color: Colors.red)),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Some Text here",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize:
                          constraints.maxHeight * .1, // change the font size
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),

                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    indent: constraints.maxWidth * .1,
                    endIndent: constraints.maxWidth * .1,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And you

```dart
  SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            child: ImageStack(),
          ),
```

[image]

If you want more control, you can use also use `FittedBox`, `auto_text_size` or

```dart
  SizedBox(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth * .8,
                    child: Text(
                      "Some Text here",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: constraints.maxHeight * .05 +
                            constraints.maxWidth * .05, // change the font size
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: it will not work on every screen as you are using fixed `Alignment(0, .1)` - if you want the first widget to be centered and the second one to be below you need to use `CustomMultiChildLayout` - not only it will work on every screen but also your code will be more simple - one "delegate" class could be used in multiple places

Comment: I've tested on web resizing the width and height. and `Alignment` is being used based on `Stack` size. Sorry I am not getting, can you describe it?

Comment: for example if your text will be longer (or screen narrower), try: `Text("Some Text here " * 2, ...)` (or 3 if it still does not wrap) and when it wraps it will break